# Can't access to nested element from parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't to acces to child's element method prom parent element using ref='menu'. When I trying call $refs.menu.show in button el, which is in Vue app element, all work fine, in photo el it doesn't work. All components registered in parent Vue app.

```
//ERROR        
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined"

    found in

    ---> <Photo>
           <Root>
```

My HTML code in #app

```
    // For tests
    <button @click.prevent='$refs.menu.show'></button>

    <div class="center" :style="{ width : center_div_width+'px', height : window_height+'px'}">
        <template v-for='(row, index1) in info'>
            // Parent element
            <photo v-for="(item, index2) in row" :item="item" :art_width='art_width'>
                // Child element
                <cmenu ref='menu'>
                    <li>Test</li>
                    <li>Test2</li>
                </cmenu>
            </photo>
        </template>
    </div>
// JS
```

My components.
I'm trying to call nested app method from template of 'photo' component:

```
Vue.component('photo', {
    props: ['item', 'art_width'],
    template: `<a class='art' href="" :style="offset(item.offsetX, item.offsetY)" @mouseover="hover = true" @mouseout="hover = false">
                   <img v-bind:src="/media/ + item.path" class="img" :width="art_width+'px'">
                   <a href="" class='art-owner' align="center" v-show='hover'>{{item.owner}}</a>
                   <a href="" class='art-menu' align="center" v-show='hover' @click.prevent='$refs.menu.show'>...</a>
                   <slot></slot>
               </a>`,
    data: function () {
        return {
            hover: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        offset (valueX, valueY) {
          return `transform: translateX(${ valueX }) translateY(${ valueY })`
        },
    },

})
context_menu = Vue.component('cmenu', {
        template: `<div class='context-menu'>
                      <ul>
                        <slot></slot> 
                      </ul>
                   </div>`,
        data: function () {
            return {
                ifshow: false,
                style = null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                if (Object.is($el, event.target) == true) {
                    this.ifshow = false;
                }
            });
        },
        methods: {
            show: function(event) {
                this.ifshow = true;
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref` is used to register a reference to an element or a child component. The reference will be registered under the parent component’s `$refs` object.

`photo` component has its own scope and its own `$refs`.

Comment: And, if my 'cmenu' component is in 'photo' and I add ref='menu', how can I access to menu from photo? from main app I can do this.

Comment: Can I call child's component method another way, not using ref?

Comment: Yes, I think that way better toom tnx, but if I add some like <cmenu v-if="menu_opened"> i get error:  [Vue warn]: Property or method "menu_opened" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: Yes, can I add code here? data: function () {
            return {
                hover: false,
                menu_opened: false
            }
        },

Comment: Yes... components: {
            context_menu: context_menu
        }

Comment: In photo's templates I use <slot></slot>, in HTML doc i add in photo component cmenu, and ref='menu' is there.

Comment: Okay, thanx for your help!